# Bash for - variable in condition

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop

This code...

```
#!/bin/bash

cond=10;

for i in {1..$cond}
do
    echo hello;
done
```

...just drives me crazy. This prints only one 'hello', as in `i` there is `{1..10}`.

```
#!/bin/bash

cond=10;

for i in {1..10}
do
    echo hello;
done
```

prints 10x hello, which is desired. How to put the variable into the condition? I tried different approaches, none of them worked. What a easy task though.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Brace expansion doesn't work with variables. You can use something like `$( seq "$cond" )` instead.

Comment: Nice solution, the Jonathan's is more universal, but this one didn't cross my mind. thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
cond=10;

for ((i=0;i<=$cond;i++));
do
    echo hello;
done
```

Comment: What a foolish man i am. I've seen a lot of various ways how to write `for`, but somehow I missed the most important one. Thank you.

Comment: (just a note, i started the `for` on 1, not 0 - not to confuse anyone)

Comment: Just to add, inside the `for` condition, it's not necessary to say `$cond`. `cond` by itself works fine too.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the classic loop already answered, you can use some magic too:

```
#!/bin/bash

cond=10

for i in $(eval "echo {1..$cond}")
do
    echo hello
done
```

But, of course, is harder to read.